# Where to find Server Control in Asp.net Web Site Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net

As you know we have both Asp.net Web Application and also Asp.net Web Site projects in VS 2017. I want to add a server control to an ASP.net website project but I could not find it. I find it easily in the ASP.net web application template.

Is it not possible to add a server control to a website project?

Update: It seems to add a custom server control I should create a web application and then add a simple Class. I used the guide in this post:

[Custom Control in ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003343/custom-control-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: You mean a `WebBrowser` control?

Comment: I mean a web server control which became web forms server control in the newest version of VS

Comment: You mean a Web User Control (.ascx)? I see it in the template for a Web Site project.

Comment: No, it is Web Forms Server Control.